# Pulse audio doesn't load at startup

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio

For a couple of days I'm facing a weird issue before that everything was working fine but now the Pulse Audio won't autostart at boot and the sound icon is missing from a panel as well. When I try to go to the *Sound Settings* there's no any *Output* or *Input* device listed, neither onboard audio nor my discrete sound card. So I execute this command in terminal:

```
rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.pulse-cookie ~/.config/pulse
```

And the sound appears right away. I tried to reinstall pulseaudio but it doesn't seem to help. Pulse Audio is listed in *Settings / Autostart Applications* and I din't make any changes to it.

What could be causing this?

Just to notice the sound icon is visible at user *login window*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the issue is solved.

I'll give a little explanation of what had happened or might happen to future readers. After the installment of discrete audio card I went into the *Sound Settings* where I checked my *Analog Outputs* and *Analog Inputs*, so as I have Xonar DG sound card which is by default aimed for *5.1 Surround Sound* and I have *2* Speakers available at the moment I tried to change it in the settings to the most suitable option for me which was *4.0 Surround* `R,R,L,L` out of the 2 options available *5.1* or *4.0*. So I selected *4.0* and after system reboot the sound didn't load at *boot* that what was causing this issue but if you *select / leave* ***5.1*** *Surround* as a default *Output* the sound will load normally but on a 2.0 Speakers you'll be missing *voice speech* for e.g. in the movies recorded with *5.1 Sound*.

So for the further notice to those who are using or will be using *2* Speakers on a *5.1* or *7.1 Surround* sound card for the *Settings* options, *etc.* use your *Output sink* as the default *Output* for the ***Headphones*** that's the *Output* for *Analog Stereo* sound as well.

Comment: I very much doubt "the sound didn't load at boot". Probably Pulseaudio and the ALSA drivers *did* load, but there was no default profile for this configuration (or whatever went wrong). If that was case, you could have fixed it with a custom profile in `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/`. Possibly it was also something else.

Comment: The thing is that it didn't even detect any sound device at all and pavucontrol didn't respond as well. I'm not sure maybe it's a bug, I tried it multiple times and the same thing happened.

Answer (score 0):

1-Open Your Terminal

```
>cd
~>nano .xprofile
```

add this line to your file

```
pulseaudio --start
```

save your file and reboot

Comment: Thank you. But it won't help in this case. Read my answer.